# C structure dereference Lvalue required

Tags: c, dereference

I am currently coding in borland C and I had a problem with structure dereference. 
 The current->value = x; is giving a Lvalue required error. This does not happen when "value" is    char. Is there anyway to assign the value of x to current->value?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

char x[16];
FILE *fin;

struct node {
    char value[16];
    struct node *next,*prev;
};
struct node *current;

void main(){
    fin = fopen("tokens.ctr","r");
    current = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    fscanf(fin,"%s",&x);
    current->value = x; 
}
```

Comment: `current->value = x; ` current->value is an array. You cannot *assign* to an array. You can only copy element-by-element, or use strcpy() or memcpy(). Also: `conio.h>` is a non-standard header, and `main()` should return int, not void.

Comment: Use `strcpy`, not assignment. Also note that `current` is a wild pointer.

Comment: You cannot assign value to an array like this, use `for` loop to assign each value individually or use `memcpy`.

Comment: You should use `strcpy`.

Comment: Tried memcpy and strcpy and it both did the job.. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, because c doesn't allow you to copy arrays like that. You have to copy each element of the array,, either with a loop or using `memcpy` ot `strcpy`

In passing,

- there's no reason for x and fin to be declared at file scope like that. You should minimise the scope of your variables.
- main must return an `int`, not a `void`
- don't cast the return from `malloc`. It returns a `void *` which can be assigned to any other pointer type.
- Your `fscanf` call is liable to undefined behaviour should any token be 16 characters or more

Answer (score 2):

Your main is wrong:

```
void main(){
  fin = fopen("tokens.ctr","r");
  current = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  fscanf(fin,"%s",&current->value);
  // current->value = x;  <-- this was wrong too, read the comments:)
}
```

And you should remember that you can read at most 15 characters (+ \0). %s will read as much as possible. You should probably use something like `%15s` or another function like `fread`, `fgets`.

Edit: using `fgets` and `strncpy`, closing stream and memory:

```
void main(){
  FILE* fin = fopen("tokens.ctr","r");
  if (NULL != fin) {
    struct node* current = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (NULL != current) {
      char x[16];
      fgets(x, sizeof(x), fin); // fread(fin, 
      strncpy(current->value, x, sizeof(current->value)); 
      free(current);
    }
    fclose(fin);
  }
}
```

1. No need to declare global variables for thing that looks like local variable
2. Variable are initialized where they are needed (it might not work with all C standard, but it should with `--std=c99`)
3. `fgets` reads in at most one less than *sizeof(x)* characters from *fin*. You won't have to maintain a relation between `%15s` and size of `x`.
4. `strncpy` copy at most `sizeof(current->value)` from `x` to `current->value`.
5. I don't know if it was a simple sample, but never forget to free the resource you use when you no longer need them.

Comment: The current->value=x was my problem and I just used the strcpy. The %15s was helpful too so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
fscanf(fin,"%s",&x);
current->value = x;
```

should be:

```
fscanf(fin, "%s", x);
strcpy(current->value, x);
```

or:

```
fscanf(fin, "%s", current->value);
```